# Why missing one character from my regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, onkeyup

I have a very good regex function which call in here:

```
<input onkeyup="vimeo();">
```

But the problem is, when the user paste a link in to the input, he get this link:

```
//player.imeo.com/video/VIDEOID
```

You see? Missing "v" from vimeo and I can't pass on this problem.
If I delete the "/" character before of "v" I get repeated value, for example:

```
//player.player.player.player.player.player.player.player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEOID
```

My replace script looks like this:

```
var vimeo = function(){
  var str2;
  $('#url').keyup(function(){
    str2 = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str2.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '\/\/player/\.\vimeo\.\com\/video/$1'));
  });
};
```

How can I fix missing "v" without repeat any value?

**Update:**

Demo link is here:

http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/addvideos/

Comment: What do you want the final value to be?

Comment: I get even more weird outcomes.. what is your input?

Comment: `\v`  => `v`, why would you escape it? `\v` is a vertical tab.

Comment: Well the link is store in mysql database and after then I echo on php with iframe.

Comment: I don't wana escape it but if I can't do it, I get repeated value.

Comment: Input example:
http://vimeo.com/113221063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your replacement string.  You don't need to escape any characters.  The second argument of the replace method takes a string, not another regular expression.

```
'\/\/player/\.\vimeo\.\com\/video/$1'
```

You can just do this:

```
'//player.vimeo.com/video/$1'
```

I am not sure why you are using a keyup event on your input as well as your url element, however.

I changed your function a bit and it works for me.

**EDIT** 
Since you want to only use one field, you'll need to use onchange to format the url once the user is done editing.  I've changed the function to reflect this change. Notice, you don't even need jQuery anymore.

```js
var vimeo = function(elem) {
  var str2 = elem.value;
  elem.value = str2.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '//player.vimeo.com/video/$1');

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onchange="vimeo(this);">
```

Comment: Yes, this working.
But I realy sorry for I can't produkate a pretty live event.
The final finish is:
This page should be everything on live.
(live save on database when you typing, replce links in typing etc).

Comment: Anyway if you edit your answer for onchange I acept it and thanks for you improvents.